# "Would have been" Vs "Would be"

Tags: difference, subjunctives, will-would

What's the difference between these two examples:

1."Your father **would be** proud of us."

2."Your father **would have been** proud of us."

Answer (score 6):

In the first example, the second conditional expresses a hypothesis on a **present** situtation, imagining an impossible or unlikely event.

> Your father would be proud of us (if he were here **now**)

It might as well imply he is dead, or simply away.

In the second example, the third conditional expresses a hypothesis on a **past** situation.

> Your father would have been proud of us (if he had been there to see
>   us)

We don't know if the father is dead now or even if he was dead at the time of the past action. We only know he was not there and so it was impossible for him to feel proud of us.

Comment: It may be described as a structure that expresses a conjecture about the future and present, having the grammatical form of the modal verb **would** plus **Infinitive of VP**. But, in case of the construction of modal verb **would** plus **Perfect Infinitive of VP**, it may be described as a structure that expresses a conjecture about the past.

Answer (score 2):

The connotation of

- Your father would be proud of us.

Is that he would be proud *if he was here and knew we did [x]*.

The connotation of

- Your father would have been proud of us.

Is that he would be proud of us *if he were still alive and knew we did [x]*. He is presumed to be *dead*.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is purely hypothetical that nobody will ever know if what have been done is something that a father should be proud of while the second sentence is something  that they have done to be proud of by any father but the thing is it will never happen because the father was not able to witness or see what they have done.

Comment: " Your father would be proud of us. " This is something that nobody can tell whether the father will be really proud or not to what have been done. there's always a question on what would be the feeling of the father if he was there.

Comment: " Your father would have been proud of us. " Is something which is quite sure that the father would be be happy if he was just there.