# “How great it would be” vs “how great it would’ve been”

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference

What's the difference between their meanings and which one is correct?

1. Imagine how great it would be if i wasn’t sick yesterday

Or

2. Imagine how great it would’ve been if i wasn’t sick yesterday

Thanks in advance

Comment: Both are correct but it would've been great if you had completed sentences :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Would have been" Vs "Would be".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56983/would-have-been-vs-would-be) Also [“Would have been” or “Would be”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/157958/would-have-been-or-would-be) and [Would be vs would have been](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/157875/would-be-vs-would-have-been), among others.

Comment: "...if I hadn't been sick yesterday."

Comment: @KateBunting: or [*if I **hadn't have been** sick yesterday.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22hadn%27t+have+been%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Is there even such a tense as _had (not) have been_?

Comment: @KateBunting: Well, my link above is to an awful lot of written instances, for a "non-existent" verb tense! :) As I understand it, at least *some* Americans would say that should be [*If I **wouldn't have** been sick*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22If+I+wouldn%27t+have+been%22), but I think that's just "weird".

Comment: [...I asked about this years ago on ELU.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62482/if-i-would-have-lost-you-vs-if-i-had-lost-you)